# This occurs when I open admin or front on localhost

Tags: php, errors

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in H:\xampp\htdocs\edventus\wp-includes\default-constants.php on line 252

Comment: Have you recently put anything in wp-config.php?

Comment: no i did  not add in this file

Answer (score 0):

What version of WordPress are you running? Can you perhaps include the code from line 252 of that file? If it's a current installation of WordPress, then it's this:

```
/**
 * @since 1.2.0
 */
if ( !defined('COOKIEPATH') )
  define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );
```

... And I can't really see why that all of a sudden should fail. ... So perhaps try and activate another theme, to see if it's some buggy code in your current theme - or if it's a corrupt WordPress installation.

In order to debug it, then you could (TEMPORARILY!!) change it to this, and reload a page and see what it outputs:

```
/**
 * @since 1.2.0
 */
if ( !defined('COOKIEPATH') ){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r( get_option('home') );
  echo '</pre>';
  die();
  define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );
}
```

If you have access to the database, then you could also see in `wp_options`-table, what the value for `option_name=home` is. Maybe something or someone changed the home-name to something mysterical.

... Or since it's a local installation, then it could be because of a space in the folder-name (in case that you changed the path for security's sake)?